# How to return JSON in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In the rails console if I type:

```
User.all.to_json
```

I get the following returned.

```
"[{\"created_at\":\"2013-04-29T23:10:36Z\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"id\":2,\"updated_at\":\"2013-04-29T23:10:36Z\"},{\"created_at\":\"2013-03-18T04:53:42Z\",\"email\":\"sharataka@gmail.com\",\"id\":1,\"updated_at\":\"2013-05-01T12:03:01Z\"}]"
```

When copy/paste this to `http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/` and try to view it as JSON, I get an error saying 'Invalid JSON Variable'.  I believe this is because of the '\' characters.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: What is `User.all` without `to_json`?

Comment: If you do that in your console, it's "normal" that the output contains several quotes and backslashes, try `puts User.all.to_json` in your console.

Comment: @MrYoshiji  Do you want to write an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Oh great, will do in a sec

Comment: What's the point of this question, anyway? In Rails you render json to a client, and that's where it matters if it's valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do that in your console, it's "normal" that the output contains several quotes and backslashes.

In my irb console:

```
irb(main):009:0> Patient.first.to_json
#=> "{\"patient\":{\"created_at\":\"2013-03-14T16:53:52-04:00\",\"id\":6538,\"updated_at\":\"2013-03-14T16:53:52-04:00\"}}"
```

But using the method `puts`:

```
irb(main):010:0> puts Patient.first.to_json
{"patient":{"created_at":"2013-03-14T16:53:52-04:00","id":6538,"updated_at":"2013-03-14T16:53:52-04:00"}}
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

- `to_json` returns a JSON string with escaped quotes etc.
- `as_json` returns it as actual JSON, this is what would validate properly.

Which you use depends on how you're rendering it.

Comment: I tried using as_json, but now it has the '=>' and I'm still getting the same error saying it's not a valid JSON variable.

Comment: @sharataka As I said, it depends on how you're rendering it. to_json is fine if you're using `puts` or sending it as a string to the browser. If you're using normal Rails JSON rendering you'd use `as_json`.